C /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lt: No such file or directory
I'm trying run unit tests for a school project using a the given Makefile but I am facing an error that I don't know how to solve:
Here are what I believe are the relevant parts in the Makefile:
CC=gcc
SDL=/usr/include/SDL2

CFLAGS_D=-g -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -O0 -D_REENTRANT -D_DEBUG -DSTRICT_THREADING -I$(SDL)
CFLAGS=-Wall -Wextra -O2 -D_REENTRANT -I$(SDL)
LD=gcc
LDFLAGS=-lm -lrt -L$(SDL) -lSDL2 -lSDL2_ttf -lSDL2_gfx -ldl -lpthread
LDFLAGS_D= $(LDFLAGS) #-lmcheck
LDFLAGS_T=-lm -lrt -L. -lt
OBJECTS= \
    point.o graphe.o \
    parse_util.o graphe_parse.o \
    liste_noeud.o dijkstra.o \
    viewport.o \
    graphrep.o window.o app.o
OBJECTS_D= $(subst .o,.do,$(OBJECTS))

VALGRIND=valgrind --leak-check=full -s

runtest_liste_noeud: test_liste_noeud
    @echo "================= [Test de liste_noeud] ================="
    ./test_liste_noeud


test_liste_noeud.o: test_liste_noeud.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_D) -c $< -o $@


test_liste_noeud: test_liste_noeud.o graphe.do point.do liste_noeud.do
    $(LD) $^ -o $@ $(LDFLAGS_T)

%.o: %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.do: %.c %.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS_D) -c $< -o $@

However, when I try to execute make test_liste_noeud
I face the following error :
gcc test_liste_noeud.o graphe.do point.do liste_noeud.do -o test_liste_noeud -lm -lrt -L. -lt
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lt: No such file or directory
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [Makefile:97: test_liste_noeud] Error 1

I have no idea how to solve this issue, does someone know a way to fix this ?
I have tried looking in /usr/bin/ld for -lt and I indeed can't find it, am I missing libraries ?
I also tried it on my school's computers via ssh/scp, where it is supposed to work, but faced the same error.

Try to put -L. last. Or ask whoever gave you that makefile.

Update for anyone that may get the same issue :
I managed to solve it :
-L locates where -lt is supposed to locate the required library with a given path. Here -L. means that the library is located in ./.
-lt means that the required library is libt.a
I could either move libt.a to ./ or change the compilation option to -L<path> -lt
